# at&t mov command, value or address written in destiny?

Tags: assembly

there ary a lot of variants how to use move, but what is written with which of them?

```
mov %ecx,0x8(%edi)
```

1. value in %ecx to stack with address 0x8(%edi) or address in %ecx to
   stack with address 0x8(%edi)?
2. has a register a pointer to a
   stack-position at every time?
3. Is the difference between (%edi) and
   %edi, that %edi is the address and (%edi) the value on this address?

Comment: There are tons of assembler languages, which one are you using?

Comment: @Kevin From the `ecx` and `edi`, it looks like its either x86 or x86-64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:** Value or address? I'm kind of confused by what you mean by this, so I'll just explain what `mov %ecx, 0x8(%edi)` does. The *value in* `ecx` will be stored at the *memory location* [edi + 8]. So, if `ecx` held the value 42, after the execution of this command, you would see the value 42 at [edi + 8] in memory. The C equivalent of this code is: `*(((char*) edi) + 8) = ecx;`

**Question 2:** A register *can* hold a position in the stack, but it doesn't have to. It can hold anything that will fit in it, be it a few characters, an integer, a pointer, whatever.

**Question 3:** `mov (%edi), eax` is moving the value at the memory location `edi`. You're *dereferencing* `edi`. The equivalent C code would be `eax = *edi`.`mov %edi, eax` is moving the value in `edi`. The equivalent C code would be `eax = edi`.

**Note:** Look at Ol' Wumpus's comment for some important info I didn't put in here.

Comment: I'd add that `0x8(%edi)` can represent an object of any size starting at address `edi + 8`, and in the example given the size of the `mov` is determined by the size of the other parameter (`%ecx`). The C equivalent with all sizes explicit would be `*(int32_t)((char *)edi+8) = ecx;`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley That's true, I'm pointing to your comment in my answer.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I think you mean this: `*(int32_t*)((char *)edi+8) = ecx;`? Also, i'm wondering, why do you cast to a `char*`? Couldn't you just do this: `*(int32_t*)(edi+8) = ecx;`?

Comment: Yes, that's better. And if this instruction resulted from actual compiled C code, `edi` was probably a pointer to some 32-bit type, so pointer arithmetic on it would be multiplied by 4. If `int *edi;` then `edi[2]` will be `%edi+8` at the assembly level.